# EJB and the Web Tier

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, ejb, java-ee-5

I am learning EJB and to do that I bought a book name EJB 3 Developer Guides.  I got some understanding on how EJB architecture is and how it works.  The book does well in explaining this.

But the examples in the book are all run through ant task.  I basically wanted to learn how EJB's are being used in conjunction with Servlets and JSP.  Some sort of a web client accessing a JSP page and a servlet getting the service of an EJB bean?

Any idea how can I move forward learning how to use EJB with the Web Tier?  Tutorials or links would be better or is there any other book that I could read?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simple EJB3 Servlet Application](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2007/07/simple-ejb-3-servlet-application.html)

And another option is [Netbeans Java EE and Java Web Tutorials](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html) -- a best bet, if you are using Netbeans. And if you are not, and you are new to Java, I would highly recommend you [Netbeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/index.html). It is simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Important note: if you try running the "Simple EJB3 Servlet Application" from the link about be sure you are using an appropriate version of Glassfish. It might work on JBoss 5.x - but I've never tested it ([according to JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.0/html/Injecting_EJB_in_Servlets.html)). 
You won't be able to run on the sample application on older versions of JBoss (like 4.2.x) without some workarounds - like ones I described in one of my posts: [sample application](https://github.com/kubamarchwicki/rest-app/)

The Netbeans tutorial seems fine - but stick to the environment and platform they are describing - otherwise you might quickly discourage and give up.

--Jakub